# Javascript setTimout in loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I want to print the array in descending order with a setTimeout. I don't know why the below code is not working in descending order.

```js
let delay = 1000;
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for(let i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(array[i - 1]);
      }, delay * i);
}
```

Expected output is `5 4 3 2 1` with one second delay. But it's printing `1 2 3 4 5`
If I remove the `i` from `setTimeOut()` it will output as expected but won't work with the delay.

Really appreciate the help.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this https://jsfiddle.net/db5cghna/ and this https://jsfiddle.net/db5cghna/1/ help?

Comment: At every cicle you're setting the delay like this: `delay * i`, with `i` ranging from 5 to 1. That means your timeouts will expire in reverse order: 5000 (set at the first cycle) will expire after 4000 (set at the second cycle) and so on. The first timeout to expire will be the one set at the last cycle (1000).

Comment: @jabaa Yea, thank you.

Comment: @Ibsn, Thanks. I understand the mistake. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bcz you say to JS print "5" after five seconds, then print "4" after four seconds then print "3" after three seconds and so on... Actually the code is just doing what you said. You can do something like this

```js
let delay = 1000;
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for(let i = array.length, j = 0; i > 0; i--, j++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(array[i - 1]);
      }, delay * j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's something like that that you want to do :

```js
let delay = 1000;
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for(let i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(array[i - 1]);
      }, delay * (array.length - i));
}
```